# Use the Python trained model for Pyspark Dataframe

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, sklearn-pandas

in order to train a model I trained a dataset on Logistic Regression to start with and using that model in below script but it gives me an error saying
**"No module named 'sklearn'"**
I have installed the package there but still doesn't work. Can someone please tell me as to what can be done?
Here is the script I found on this [blog](https://towardsdatascience.com/deploy-a-python-model-more-efficiently-over-spark-497fc03e0a8d)

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as f
import pyspark.sql.types as t
from pyspark.sql.window import Window as w

model = LogisticRegression(C=1e5)
model.fit(X, Y)

#creating test data from Pyspark
vectorAssembler = VectorAssembler(inputCols = [col for col in df.columns if '_id' not in col and 'label' not in col], outputCol="features")
features_vectorized = vectorAssembler.transform(df)

model_broadcast = sc.broadcast(model)
# udf to predict on the cluster
def predict_new(feature_map):
    ids, features = zip(*[
        (k,  v) for d in feature_map for k, v in d.items()
    ])
    ind = model_broadcast.value.classes_.tolist().index(1.0)
    probs = [
        float(v) for v in 
        model_broadcast.value.predict_proba(features)[:, ind]
    ]
    return dict(zip(ids, probs))
predict_new_udf = f.udf(
    predict_new, 
    t.MapType(t.LongType(), t.FloatType()
))
# set the number of prediction groups to create
nparts = 5000
# put everything together
outcome_sdf = (
                features_vectorized.select(
                            f.create_map(f.col('id'), f.col('features')).alias('feature_map'), 
                            (f.row_number().over(w.partitionBy(f.lit(1)).orderBy(f.lit(1))) % nparts).alias('grouper')
                          )
                .groupby(f.col('grouper'))
                .agg(f.collect_list(f.col('feature_map')).alias('feature_map'))
                .select(predict_new_udf(f.col('feature_map')).alias('results'))
                .select(f.explode(f.col('results')).alias('unique_id', 'probability_estimate'))
            )
```

This runs and also executes well but when I look for values of the outcome_sdf, I get an error with no module named sklearn. I read about installing sklearn in cluster, can someone help me with that?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to install `sklearn` in **all nodes** of your cluster, not a single node.

Comment: So to do that. I ran **pip install -U scikit-learn** and similar for spark-sklearn. But it didn't work. Do I need to do it differently? @pltc

Comment: As I said, you have to do that with **all of your worker node**, not the one where you run your script. Or are you saying you have only one node?

Comment: I am creating a virtual environment everytime using 
```conf spark.pyspark.virtualenv.enabled=true
    --conf spark.pyspark.virtualenv.type=native
    --conf spark.pyspark.virtualenv.bin.path=/usr/bin/virtualenv```. And when that is happening, the pip install is not working on this environment. Any idea on this?

Comment: If you're using virtualenv, make sure you update `requirements.txt` accordingly

Comment: Can it be done using some script to be included in above mentioned script?